# Twitter-bootstrap row-fluid up to span12 only

Tags: html, css, grails, twitter-bootstrap

I was working with twitter-bootstrap. I used the class row-fluid. But it seems that the maximum span for it is only 12. I tried to override it by adding span16 but it seems its not working. Is their another way around it? thanks.

PS. I used the latest twitter-bootstrap.

Comment: Why do you need span 16 class?

Comment: I have exactly 16 div's which I want to aligned in one row. When I added span16, the rest of the div comes down at the bottom of the other div. Do you know how to make it work? Their is some reason beneath this thats why I'm eager to find the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GaurishSharma if you have a solution on how to make this work, you can post it in the answer so I can upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize your Bootstrap grid and set as many columns as you need. [Here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) is the link.

Answer (score 0):

Since at least the last two versions, Bootstrap has switched to a 12 column layout from a 16 column one. I know it makes upgrading hard, I had to make changes all over my website too! However, 12 is better than 16 as in there are more divisors so more ratios possible -like 1/3rd :)